# Why helm template function is not resolveing $labels var?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am defining a PrometheusRule  as follow:

```
prometheusRule:
  rules:
    - alert: SSLCertExpiringSoon
      expr: probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry - time() < 86400 * 10
      for: 0m
      labels:
        severity: warning
      annotations:
        summary: Blackbox SSL certificate will expire soon (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
        description: "SSL certificate expires in 30 days\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

And the template yml from helm chart:

```
{{- if .Values.prometheusRule.enabled }}
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: {{ template "prometheus-blackbox-exporter.fullname" . }}
  {{- with .Values.prometheusRule.namespace }}
  namespace: {{ . }}
  {{- end }}
  labels:
    {{- include "prometheus-blackbox-exporter.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- with .Values.prometheusRule.additionalLabels -}}
{{- toYaml . | nindent 4 -}}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- with .Values.prometheusRule.rules }}
  groups:
    - name: {{ template "prometheus-blackbox-exporter.name" $ }}
      rules: {{ tpl (toYaml .) $ | nindent 8 }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

when I run `helm template`, `tpl` func it is not resolving the $labels and $values vars. When I remove annotations then the helm template is not complaining anymore. Where do fail?

error:

```
Error: template: prometheus-blackbox-exporter/templates/prometheusrule.yaml:18:16: executing "prometheus-blackbox-exporter/templates/prometheusrule.yaml" at <tpl (toYaml .) $>: error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "- alert: SSLCertExpiringSoon\n  annotations:\n    summary: Blackbox SSL certificate will expire soon (instance {{ $labels.instance\n      }})\n  expr: probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry - time() < 86400 * 10\n  for: 0m\n  labels:\n    release: prometheus\n    severity: warning\n- alert: SSLCertExpiringSoon\n  annotations: null\n  expr: probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry - time() < 86400 * 3\n  for: 0m\n  labels:\n    severity: critical": parse error at (prometheus-blackbox-exporter/templates/prometheusrule.yaml:3): undefined variable "$labels"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prometheus's alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) also use `{{ ... $variable ... }}` syntax, similar to Helm but with [a different variant on the Go `text/template` syntax](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/consoles/).  When you pass this file through `tpl`, *Helm* tries to evaluate the embedded `{{ ... }}` template and evaluate any blocks there.  Since `$labels` and `$value` aren't local variables defined at the Helm level, you get this error.

If you just want Prometheus to see this file as-is, and you don't need to replace anything at the Helm level (the file doesn't include references to `.Values`) then you don't need `tpl`

```yaml
      rules: {{ toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
```

If you do need `tpl`, then inside the included file you need to cause `{{` to be emitted as a string and not processed as a template.  One syntactic approach to it is to create a template block that prints out `{{`:

```yaml
description: "VALUE = {{ "{{" }} $value }}"
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^ a {{ ... }} block that prints "{{"
```

Comment: still issue is there. I need tpl function. when I replace with your version then getting `Error: failed to parse values.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 56: did not find expected key`

Comment: Since your @David Maze answer is the closest to solution I marked as answer , you may edit as I write below

Answer (score 1):

The working version of syntax is as follow:

```
{{ `{{` }} $value }}
```